# Horror movie where chicken is full of worms

Tags: story-identification, horror

This scene has been in the back of my mind for 30 years, and I've never stumbled across the movie I saw it in.  This would most likely be a horror movie from the '70's or '80's.  All I can remember is a scene where a young women takes a bite from a piece of chicken, and the chicken is full of worms (or maggots).  I feel like the girl was either hallucinating or dreaming, but that is really all I can remember about the film.

Comment: Perhaps?  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QsMCOmn11zs

Comment: I can't tell if it's the same as the aforementioned clip, as I cannot currently view videos, but *The Curse* aka *The Farm* (1987) includes segments where the farm's contents are infested with maggots, although the references I've found indicate that the chickens have "green slime" in them. Wil Wheaton was in it apparently.

Comment: sounds like "A Night at McDonald's" to me.

Comment: That clip from Poltergeist is what I immediately thought of when chicken and maggots were mentioned.  It's a young man instead of a young woman, but other than that it's a solid match.  The scene goes on to have the poor sap hallucinate that he's tearing his own face off but he snaps out of it at the end.

Comment: Following up, the trailer at http://youtu.be/mOpJbyd9ick shows worms in an apple and later shows a chicken leaking green slime, but no worms directly in the hicken. Sorry.

Comment: [someone who actually found live wriggling maggots in his fried chicken](http://www.worldstarhiphop.com/videos/video.php?v=wshhhZgzvxerPc6416eb). Ugh.

Comment: Just to confirm, @Zachary, but the trailer for *The Curse* does not look like the right movie?

Answer (score -1):

Could it be the movie 'Squirm?' It's from 1976 and had flesh-eating worms.

Comment: Maybe "The Lost Boys" but it's a male teen, not a woman